# Formal way of proving that the ring $2 \Bbb Z_{10}$ has an additive inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing

I'm trying to find a formal way of proving that the ring $2 \Bbb Z_{10}$ has an additive inverse. I understand that 8+2 = 0 mod 10 and 6+4 = 0 mod 10, etc. Is there a way to formally prove this is true?

Comment: You mean that *elements of* the ring have additive inverses?  Can you use the fact that elements of $\mathbb Z_{10}$ have additive inverses?

Comment: Yes, the elements...sorry. For instance to prove the additive inverse for the complex numbers, I could say something like $x+(-x) = (a+bi)+(-a-bi) = (a-a)+(b-b)i = 0+0i = 0$. Just wondering if I could write something similar to that, but for the integers $2 \Bbb Z_{10}$.

Comment: Hint: $[2k]+[10-2k]=[0]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $ \mathbb{Z}_{10} $ is a ring it is a group under an operation $+$ and every element has an inverse.  Let $z \in \mathbb{Z}_{10} $, then there exists $-z$ such that $ z - z = 0 $.  Since $ \mathbb{Z}_{10} $ is a ring then $ 2 (z - z) = 2 (0) = 0$ and from the distributive property of a ring it follows that $2z - 2z = 0$ for all $2z \in 2 \mathbb{Z}_{10} $ where $z \in \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ because of the second operation of the ring.

Comment: Here I've just used the absorbing property of the additive identity under the second operation as a sort of lemma but if this is unclear it's an easy proof you can do.